# Prove $\mbox{rank} (A − B) = \mbox{rank} (A − AB) + \mbox{rank}(B − AB)$, if $A^2 = A$ and $B^2 = B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank, idempotents

How would one prove following?

> If $A^2 = A$ and $B^2 = B$, then show that $$\mbox{rank} (A − B) = \mbox{rank} (A − AB) + \mbox{rank} (B − AB)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $A - B = A(A - B) - (B-A)B$ we have by subadditivity that $$\mbox{rank}(A - B) \leq \mbox{rank} (A(A-B)) + \mbox{rank} ((B-A)B) = \mbox{rank} (A - AB) + \mbox{rank} (B - AB)$$

On the other hand, using Frobenius' rank inequality and noting that $A(A - B)B = 0$:

$$\mbox{rank} (A(A -B)) + \mbox{rank} ((A-B)B) \leq \mbox{rank} (A - B) + \mbox{rank} (A(A-B)B) = \mbox{rank} (A - B))$$